# Definition of "smallness" in Lurie's HTT

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Lurie's [*Higher Topos Theory*](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/croppedtopoi.pdf), on the first page of the appendix, he writes

> If $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, we will say that a set $S$ is $\kappa$-small if it has cardinality less than $\kappa$.

Is this really what he intended, or is this a typo and should be *rank* instead of *cardinality*?

Comment: That's way out of my expertise but especially given the restriction to regular cardinals, I'd assume he meant what he wrote. Why do you suspect otherwise?

Comment: Mostly because on the next page, he writes: "*… we will adopt the usual device of Grothendieck universes. We fix a strongly inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ and refer to a mathematical object (such as a set or category) as small if it is $\kappa$-small, and large otherwise.*" We need to consider the set of sets of *rank* $< \kappa$ in order to get a Grothendieck universe, I think.

Comment: On the other hand, he doesn't claim that the Grothendieck universe is precisely the set of all ($\kappa$-)small sets… so perhaps you're right.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification. Still, isn't the rank usually an ordinal (not a cardinal)?

Comment: Having browsed around a bit I would speculate it should actually neither cardinality nor rank, but *type* (or maybe strict type). Meaning that everything that is an element or an element or an element etc has cardinality at most the given cardinal. Or, he means cardinality there and the latter paraphrase is imprecise.